# Add style attribute to view fields

Tags: views, theming

I would like to add a style attribute to each title fields in my view. I have created one field for a color. I tried to rewrite the result like this:

```
<h2 style="color: [field_color];">[title_1]</h2>
```

But the style attribute will be removed. I'm using Drupal 7.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why is it removed? Have you tried using a global text field instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean with a global text field? The settings in my view:

Format: Unformatted list
Show: Fields

Comment: You have the option to add a 'global text' field. This field must go after any other fields you have already added. You can then use tokens in this custom field to create similar to what you have done above. You can then hide the fields that are shown in the custom field.

Comment: I tried to add a global text field after my other fields. I added the same code as before in the text field, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Were those tokens above available in the 'token replacements'?

Comment: Yes, the tokens are available in the list "Replacement patterns". I can se the value from [field_color] if I'm printing the value without any style tag. So I think the problem is the style tag. I have also tried to add a style tag with an other value. For example: <h2 style="color: red;">[title_1]</h2>. But the style tag will be removed.

Comment: Your best option is to probably create a custom template file for this field or use a class based on the token mentioned below.

Comment: Yes I think you have right. But I don't know what template I should use for that.

Comment: If you look under 'Advanced' on the right-hand side theres an option for 'Theme information', here it will give you some suggestions for templates.

Comment: I found the templates, but I couldn't find the variables from the fields and the html for the elements that I need.

Comment: Where you get the template suggestions theres a link beside each of them that has the code required for that template.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a class to the title field using Style Settings as shown below screen. You can user token replacements in style settings to set class to the title field.

[image]

Using small javascript or jquery read the class of title field and set the color same as class name using [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property.

Comment: Maybe your solution works, but I what to solve this without javascript. Is is possible?

Comment: You cannot directly inject the field value to style property due to security issues.. See the issue here http://drupal.org/node/853880

Comment: Then you need to write separate css class for each color, however this is worst case, cause you need to write 16 million class :(. Javascript or jquery would be better.

Comment: Anil, I tried your solution but Drupal removed # from the color, so I found another solution with jQuery. I added the attribute data to the field:

<h2 data-color="[field_color]">[title_1]</h2>

I have investigated other solutions with templates, but I couldn't find the right way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tpl for this field (example: views-view-field-MY-VIEW-NAME-page.tpl.php), in this tpl you can add the token writing this:

```
<h2 style="color: <?php print $field->last_tokens['[field_color]'] ?>;"><?php print $field->last_tokens['[title_1]'] ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had to include the value of a field as an inline color for a particular field.
After browsing the web for an easy customizable solution, I ended up doing this:

1. Add the value of the color as a CSS Class token, just like the image in the previous post.
2. Rewrite the [hook_preprocess_views_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7) function like this:

   ```
    function hook_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
     $view = $vars['view'];

     // Loop through the fields for this view.
     $previous_inline = FALSE;
     $vars['fields'] = array(); // ensure it's at least an empty array.
     foreach ($view->field as $id => $field) {

       // render this even if set to exclude so it can be used elsewhere.
       $field_output = $view->style_plugin->get_field($view->row_index, $id);
       $empty = $field->is_value_empty($field_output, $field->options['empty_zero']);
       if (empty($field->options['exclude']) && (!$empty || (empty($field->options['hide_empty']) && empty($vars['options']['hide_empty'])))) {
         $object = new stdClass();
         $object->handler = & $view->field[$id];
         $object->inline = !empty($vars['options']['inline'][$id]);

         $object->element_type = $object->handler->element_type(TRUE, !$vars['options']['default_field_elements'], $object->inline);
         if ($object->element_type) {
           $class = '';
           if ($object->handler->options['element_default_classes']) {
             $class = 'field-content';
           }

           if ($classes = $object->handler->element_classes($view->row_index)) {
             if ($class) {
               $class .= ' ';
             }
             $class .= $classes;
           }

           $class_array = explode(' ', $class);
           foreach ($class_array as $cid => $candidate) {
             // Find the color hex code.
             if (preg_match('/([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/', $candidate)) {
               $style = 'color:#' . $candidate . ';';
               unset($class_array[$cid]);
             }
           }

           $pre = '<' . $object->element_type;
           if ($class) {
             $pre .= ' class="' . implode(' ', $class_array) . '"';
           }
           if ($style) {
             $pre .= ' style="' . $style . '"';
           }
           $field_output = $pre . '>' . $field_output . '</' . $object->element_type . '>';
         }

         // Protect ourself somewhat for backward compatibility. This will prevent
         // old templates from producing invalid HTML when no element type is selected.
         if (empty($object->element_type)) {
           $object->element_type = 'span';
         }

         $object->content = $field_output;
         if (isset($view->field[$id]->field_alias) && isset($vars['row']->{$view->field[$id]->field_alias})) {
           $object->raw = $vars['row']->{$view->field[$id]->field_alias};
         }
         else {
           $object->raw = NULL; // make sure it exists to reduce NOTICE
         }

         if (!empty($vars['options']['separator']) && $previous_inline && $object->inline && $object->content) {
           $object->separator = filter_xss_admin($vars['options']['separator']);
         }

         $object->class = drupal_clean_css_identifier($id);

         $previous_inline = $object->inline;
         $object->inline_html = $object->handler->element_wrapper_type(TRUE, TRUE);
         if ($object->inline_html === '' && $vars['options']['default_field_elements']) {
           $object->inline_html = $object->inline ? 'span' : 'div';
         }

         // Set up the wrapper HTML.
         $object->wrapper_prefix = '';
         $object->wrapper_suffix = '';

         if ($object->inline_html) {
           $class = '';
           if ($object->handler->options['element_default_classes']) {
             $class = "views-field views-field-" . $object->class;
           }

           if ($classes = $object->handler->element_wrapper_classes($view->row_index)) {
             if ($class) {
               $class .= ' ';
             }
             $class .= $classes;
           }

           $object->wrapper_prefix = '<' . $object->inline_html;
           if ($class) {
             $object->wrapper_prefix .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
           }
           $object->wrapper_prefix .= '>';
           $object->wrapper_suffix = '</' . $object->inline_html . '>';
         }

         // Set up the label for the value and the HTML to make it easier
         // on the template.
         $object->label = check_plain($view->field[$id]->label());
         $object->label_html = '';
         if ($object->label) {
           $object->label_html .= $object->label;
           if ($object->handler->options['element_label_colon']) {
             $object->label_html .= ': ';
           }

           $object->element_label_type = $object->handler->element_label_type(TRUE, !$vars['options']['default_field_elements']);
           if ($object->element_label_type) {
             $class = '';
             if ($object->handler->options['element_default_classes']) {
               $class = 'views-label views-label-' . $object->class;
             }

             $element_label_class = $object->handler->element_label_classes($view->row_index);
             if ($element_label_class) {
               if ($class) {
                 $class .= ' ';
               }

               $class .= $element_label_class;
             }

             $pre = '<' . $object->element_label_type;
             if ($class) {
               $pre .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
             }
             $pre .= '>';

             $object->label_html = $pre . $object->label_html . '</' . $object->element_label_type . '>';
           }
         }

         $vars['fields'][$id] = $object;
       }
     }

   }
   ```

As you can see, I've added these lines:

```
$style = '';
$class_array = explode(' ', $class);
foreach ($class_array as $cid => $candidate) {
  // Find the color hex code.
  if (preg_match('/([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/', $candidate)) {
    $style = 'color:#' . $candidate . ';';
    unset($class_array[$cid]);
  }
}
```

And change the line under:

```
$pre = '<' . $object->element_type;
if ($class) {
  $pre .= ' class="' . implode(' ', $class_array) . '"';
}
if ($style) {
  $pre .= ' style="' . $style . '"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a name into the field anil suggested then open style.css in your theme folder and type ".my-css-name" followed by desired css results such as:

.my-css-name {
 color:red;
 background:green;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making something similar and here is what i did:

1- Create a view with color and title fields.

2- Create a custom "views-view-fields.tpl" for that view. (A custom template only for the color field, showed me an error)

3- At `field->content` line add/replace what you need....`<h2 style="color: #<?php print $field->content; ?>">`

/ / / / From now on, i didn't test it, but it should work fine / / / /

4- Exclude the title field and show it on the header/group

5- Create a custom "views-view-unformatted.tpl" for that view.

6- In this view we add `<?php print $title; ?></h2>` after `<?php print $row; ?>`. (we add the title and close the H tag open in the first template)

---

### LAST EDIT:

You can simply use views PHP to print all the thing you need and style won't be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by creating a template named

```
views-view-field--field_name_here.tpl.php
```

In my case, the code I used to create the HTML I needed was:

```
<?php

$bg_color = $variables["row"]->field_field_button_background_color[0]["raw"]["rgb"];
$link_title = $variables["row"]->field_field_slideshow_item_cta_link[0]["raw"]["title"];
$link_url = $variables["row"]->field_field_slideshow_item_cta_link[0]["raw"]["url"];

echo '<a style="background-color:'.$bg_color.'" href="'.$link_url.'">'.$link_title.'</a>';
```

Enabling the Devel module and using

```
dpm($row);
```

in the template file was VERY helpful.  Couldn't have figured this out without it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could find was to insert the value as a data attribute.  Then in my JavaScript I take the value from the data field and update the CSS to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom field in the view as you normally would. instead of printing the style attribute as `style="xyz"` use `data-style="xyz"`. Copy the template for the default view field `views-view-field.html.twig` into your theme and replace its contents with:
`{{ output|replace({'data-style=': 'style='})|raw -}}`

When I was previously stuck with:
`<a href="/path-to-thing" class="cover-image-style">Title of node</a>`

Now I get the desired:
`<a href="/path-to-thing" style="background-image('/path/from/node/media/image.jpg')" class="cover-image-style">Title of node</a>`