# How can I add styles attribute to Global Custom field markup?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have created a view to display my articles and I would like the article thumbnails to be used as background.
So I added the different fields I've hidden.

I added a relationship to the image field to get the thumbnail URI. Then I added the following code in the custom global field.

```
<div class="post-datas" style="background-image: url('{{ uri }}')">
<span class="category-art">{{ field_categorie }}</span>
<h3 class="title-art">{{ title }}</h3>
<span class="date-art">{{ created }}</span>
</div>
```

But on display, the style is ignored.

Instead of `<div class="post-datas" style="background-image: url('http://adresse">`, I have `<div class="post-datas">`.

How can I make Views to print the style attribute to let me put a dynamic background image URI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Views removes style attribute in "Rewrite Results"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85700/views-removes-style-attribute-in-rewrite-results)

Comment: leymannx I believe the answer in the linked issue is too generic and drupal 7 specific, I am assuming op is using Drupal 8 @worksfather is that right ?

Comment: that's right @Giorgosk I'm on drupal 8. I've seen a drupal 7 solution myself. But it's not suitable for drupal 8.

Comment: Can you add which template you added that code, and also settings of your view, is it based on  Content or Fields ?

Comment: @berramou, this is not a template, this is a rewrite of the field in UI. You can try to put the twig code in a views field template similar to the linked D7 answers, but a better approach would be a custom views field plugin or, without custom code, rendering a view mode instead of fields and then use a field formatter like https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_img_field

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 views will strip away any markup it thinks it is dangerous

you have to rely on a custom theme solution here is a general overview of how this can be done

1. if you don't have a custom theme you have to create one ([more info](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme))
2. Enable Twig debugging ([more info](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374))
3. Inspect your page in browser to find the appropriate templates to override.  In the html comments you will find which .twig template is responsible to output a specific piece of html markup  ([More info](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/locating-template-files-with-debugging))
4. Copy required template into your CUSTOM_THEME/theme folder
5. Add or modify the markup in the twig template

Alternatively you might want to give https://www.drupal.org/project/viewscss a try which promises to allow viewscss but it does not have a stable release.

Comment: I tried to do that already, but I don't know what code I have to insert in the twig template to get the thumbnail url as background.

Comment: Template should have already code in ( it is copy paste from overridden theme ) ... Just modify that ... Or give more details on your actual views setup